# Playing Animation file at the start of App Android

Tags: android, animation

I've made an app and I wanted to play an animation first after I clicked to open up the app.

So I created an animation file now on the PC and I was just wondering how can I get it to play when I start up the app or is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "animation file on the PC"? Did you create a video?

Comment: Everything is possible! Play the animation in `onCreate()` of the `Activity`.

Comment: Sorry yes, I made a couple second long mp4 file and I would like to be able to have that play first when you start up the app. Sorry for not explaining better. What way would be the best way to go about this? thanks :)